# Email-ext Pre script usage

Tags: jenkins, hudson, jenkins-plugins, hudson-plugins, email-ext

How can I write a prescript to check whether an email is going to be triggered because of an upstream project cause (commit-job A).

If it does trigger, I want to cancel the email triggering in job B.
I have seen one cancel variable. I want to know how can I use it for checking and cancelling?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is get at the cause of the current build. The build is provided to the pre-send script via the "build" variable.

```
build.causes.each() { cause ->
  if(cause instanceof Cause.UpstreamCause) {
      cancel = cause.upstreamProject == 'commit-job A'
  }    
}
```

This should set the cancel variable to true if the upstream project is the one you are interested in. The cancel variable is retrieved by email-ext and if it is true, the sending of the email is stopped.